# emberjs - refactor to component helper

Tags: ember.js

I am migrating some code from ember 1.7.1 and I created my own component helper before there was one in the form of a handlebars helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('renderComponent', function(contextPath, propertyPath, options) {
  var context, helper, property;
  context = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, contextPath, options);
  property = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, propertyPath, options);
  helper = Ember.Handlebars.resolveHelper(options.data.view.container, property.component);
  options.contexts = [];
  options.types = [];
  property.bindings.forEach(function(binding) {
    options.hash[binding] = binding;
    options.hashTypes[binding] = "ID";
    options.hashContexts[binding] = context;
  });

  return helper.call(context, options);
});
```

The helper is called like this:

```
{{#each list as |item|}}
  {{#each column in columns}}
    <td>
      {{renderComponent item column}
    </td>
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

And would create components from a configuration like this:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  columns: Ember.A([
   {
      heading: "Heading",
      binding: "name",
      route: "company"
    },
    {
      heading: "Address",
      binding: "address"
    },
    {
      heading: 'full',
      component: 'full-contact',
      bindings: ['name', 'address']
    }
  ])
});
```

How can I achieve the same thing with the component helper?

I'm thinking specifically about passing arguments and bindings to the component helper?  How is that done?

Comment: Where does the "item" come from in your template? Using the component helpers is just a matter of doing `{{component 'name' 'param1' 'param2'}}

Comment: I've updated the question.  I iterate through a list of ember-data models or whatever.

From your definition, param1 and param2 seem to be positional, I thought it would be something like:

`{{component 'name' param1=value1 param2=value2}}

So I'm not sure how passing parameters or binding to values works from the component helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your update and the comments, you are on the right track. The component helpers is as you described:

```
{{component 'name' paramName='paramValue' otherParam='otherValue'}}
```

Also every property can be bound of course

```
{{component boundComponentName paramName=boundParamValue otherParam=boundOtherValue}}
```

Take a look at this [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/89f3a8ea182568f6c680) I created to illustrate. Look for the `application.hbs` file and the `my-component template/component.js` files

Comment: Thank you for this, big help!

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck with your Ember efforts!